# Um Model com 2 relacionamentos mas na view só aparece 1

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2

Tenho uma model chamada medico que pertence , a uma cidade , e pertence a uma especialidade codigo :

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Medico extends AppModel { 
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Cidade' => array(
        'className' => 'Cidade',
        'foreignKey' => 'cidade_id'
    ),
    'Especialidade' => array(
        'className' => 'Especialidade',
        'foreignKey' => 'especialidades_id'
    )
);
}
```

Beleza até ai tudo certo a model cidade tem muitos medicos:

```
App::uses('AppModel','Model');
 class Cidade extends AppModel
 {
   public $belongsTo = array(
    'Estado' => array(
        'className' => 'Estado',
        'foreingKey' => 'estado_id'
    ));

public $hasMany= array(
    'Medicos'=>array(
     'className'=>'Medico',
     'foreingKey'=>'cidade_id'
    )
);
}
```

A model especialidade tem muitos medicos

```
class Especialidade extends AppModel {

public $useTable = 'especialidades';
public $hasMany = array(
    'Medicos' => array(
        'className' => 'Medico',
        'foreignKey' => 'especialidades_id'
    )
);
}
```

Mas ao tentar cadastrar um medico na hora de adicionar a especialidade não aparece, a cidade aparece normal mas a especialidade não, o que pode estar errado?
abaixo codigo do controller

```
class MedicosController extends AppController {
public $components = array('Paginator', 'Flash');
public $helpers = array('Html','Form','Flash');
  public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Medico->create();
        if ($this->Medico->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The medico has been saved.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The medico could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-error'));
        }
    }
    $cidades = $this->Medico->Cidade->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('cidades'));
    $espcialidades = $this->Medico->Especialidade->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('espcialidades'));


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de um tempo testando entendi o porque  resolvi assim,no controller medicos eu coloquei o nome da model no plural na hora de chamar o metodo find()

```
$especialidades = $this->Medico->Especialidades->find('list',array('fields'=>array('id','especialidade')));
    $this->set(compact('cidades', 'especialidades'));
```

E isso porque a model o relacionamento tem sempre um alias e esse alias na model ficou no plural segue codigo abaixo:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Cidade' => array(
        'className' => 'Cidade',
        'foreignKey' => 'cidade_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Especialidades' => array(
        'className' => 'Especialidade',
        'foreignKey' => 'especialidades_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Bom enfim resolvido o problema!